# Make a new line when hitting the Return key on a physical iPad keyboard SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, textview

I'm having trouble creating a new line on a `TextField` when the iPad physical keyboard is attached, any idea on how to achieve this?

My code is as follows:

```
TextField("Message", text: $messageToSend, axis: .vertical)
                    .focused($editing)
```

So when I don't have the physical keyboard attached, it creates new lines and grows vertically (everything works great) but as soon as I attach the physical keyboard the return button will only resign my TextField.

Comment: Have you tried `shift + return`

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, strangely I hit `option + return` and it did the trick.

Comment: Never tried `option + return` that might be keyboard/macOS. I believe it is standard practice with an external keyboard for `return` to `submit` and for a combo to do next line.

Answer (score 1):

Well after the first comment, I realised that for the iPad physical keyboard `option + return` does the trick.